How to create a vertical bar chart with rounded containers in Vue.js using ApexCharts?
[![Image shows a minimalist vertical bar chart with 7 vertically-oriented "pill" shaped bars. Each bar consists of:

An outer container:

Light gray color (#E9EDF7)
Fully rounded ends (high border-radius)
Full height
Width approximately 16px


An inner fill bar:

Bright blue color (#1A75FF)
Matches the container's rounded style
Variable heights representing different values
Same width as container
Aligned to bottom



The bars are evenly spaced with approximately 20px between them. No axis lines, labels, or grid are shown. The first bar shows dimensions of 145.58 x 15.91 pixels. The overall effect is clean and modern, with each bar appearing as a gray pill partially filled from the bottom with blue.](https://i.sstatic.net/BOqHlTLz.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/BOqHlTLz.png)
I'm trying to create a vertical bar chart in Vue.js that has a specific design: each bar should have a light gray rounded container with a blue fill bar inside it. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[Image description: A bar chart with 7 vertical bars. Each bar has a light gray (#E9EDF7) rounded container that extends full height, with a blue (#1A75FF) rounded bar inside it showing the actual value. The bars appear to have significant border radius, giving them a pill-like shape.]
Here's my current attempt:
<template>
  <div class="p-4">
    <ClientOnly>
      <apexchart type="bar" :options="chartOptions" :series="series" height="250" />
    </ClientOnly>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const series = ref([
  {
    name: "Value",
    data: [80, 40, 70, 35, 60, 85, 25]
  }
]);

const chartOptions = ref({
  chart: {
    type: "bar",
    toolbar: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      borderRadius: 20,
      columnWidth: "25%"
    }
  },
  grid: {
    show: false
  },
  xaxis: {
    labels: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    show: false
  }
});
</script>

However, I can't figure out how to:
Create the gray container effect for each bar
Get the proper rounded corners on both the container and fill bar
Maintain consistent spacing between the bars
I'm using:
Vue 3
ApexCharts (vue3-apexcharts)
TypeScript
Has anyone achieved something similar? I'd appreciate any guidance on how to create this effect.

To set bar and bar container colors, use the colors and plotOptions.bar.colors.backgroundBarColors option:
const chartOptions = ref({
  ...
  colors: ['#1A75FF'],
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      colors: {
        backgroundBarColors: ['#e7ebf5'],
      }
    }
  },


Similarly, you can set radius with the options plotOptions.bar.borderRadius and plotOptions.bar.colors.backgroundBarRadius:
const chartOptions = ref({
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      borderRadius: 15,
      colors: {
        backgroundBarRadius: 15,
      }
    }
  },


Note thatborderRadius expects a pixel value. So unless you use fixed width, the value has to adjust for evenly rounded corners on different container/screen sizes.
One way to do this is in the updated event. It receives the chart object as parameter, so you can check radius and update it if necessary:

const updateRadius = (chart) => {
  const barWidth = chart.w.globals.barWidth
  const expectedRadius = 0.5 * barWidth
  const currentRadius = chart.w.config.plotOptions.bar.borderRadius
  
  if (currentRadius !== expectedRadius) { // <--- endless loop if you screw this up
    const optionsUpdate = {
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          borderRadius: expectedRadius,
          colors: {
            backgroundBarRadius: expectedRadius,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    chart.updateOptions(optionsUpdate, false, false)
  }
}

For other approaches (like ResizeObserver) you need a reference to the chart object, which is exposed by the apexchart component:
<template>
    <apexchart type="bar" ref="apexRef"/>
</template>
<script setup>
  const apexRef = ref() // bind template ref
  const chart = computed(() => apexRef.value.chart) // access exposed chart object
</script>

Here it is in playground

Thanks @Mortiz Ringler.
It works very well.
Happy new year!!!:)

That's great. Happy new year to you tooo!
